# non www to www redirect htaccess on laravel

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

im doing some very simple stuff with my `.htaccess` file located in my `public` directory

here is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # domain.com redirect to www.domain.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

very standard striaght out of the box stuff. but whenever i type domain.com in the browser it jsut redirects to a yahoo dns search

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

You want to redirect everything **at** `domain.com` **to** `www.domain.com`

Comment: it still redirects me to a yahoo search about DNS, im not sure what the issue is....

Comment: lol i forgot to add it. everything works now but it doesnt redirect still

Comment: Lol, does it do anything at all?

Comment: everything loads properly, but doesnt accomplish the redirect with the`.htaccess`

Comment: And you're sure the rewrite module is enabled?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102543/discussion-between-hello-world-and-samrap).

Comment: for some reason its working on my chrome browser at work, but not on mozilla

Comment: The reason why this wont work is because you are probably using `nginx`